# Integral of the difference of two identity functions

Tags: integration, probability-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, expected-value

**I'm trying to see if the following holds:**

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is always possible to write:

$$( a - b )=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(I_{\{b\leqslant x\}} - I_{ \{ a \leqslant x\}} \right)dx$$

**My steps are as follows:**

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(I_{\{b\leqslant x\}} - I_{ \{ a \leqslant x\}} \right)dx = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}I_{\{b\leqslant x\}} dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}I_{ \{ a \leqslant x\}} dx \\
= & \int_{b}^{\infty}dx - \int_{a}^{\infty} dx \\
(\textrm{replacing infinite limits with finite values})=&\lim_{c\to\infty} \left[  \int_{b}^{c}dx - \int_{a}^{c} dx \right]\\
=&\lim_{c\to\infty} \left[  (c-b)- (c-a) \right]\\
=&\lim_{c\to\infty} \left[  (a-b) \right]\\
=&(a-b)
\end{align}

I'm not sure whether my steps are valid; any pointers/insights would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

**Edited using suggestions:**

Assuming $b\leq a$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(I_{\{b\leqslant x\}} - I_{ \{ a \leqslant x\}} \right)dx = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(I_{ \{b\leqslant x \leqslant a \}} \right)dx \\
= & \int_{b}^{a}dx \\
=&(a-b)
\end{align}

Comment: No, it is invalid right at the start when you write it as $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @user10354138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not valid. The expression $\int_b^{\infty} dx-\int_a^{\infty} dx$ is not defined because both the integrals are $\infty$. To avoid this problem verify that $I_{\{b\leq x\}} -I_{\{a\leq x\}} =I_{\{b\leq x <a\}}$ and then integrate. Remark: I have assumed that $b \leq a$. Because of the symmetry in the equation there is no loss of generality in assuming this. [ If you interchange $a$ and $b$ you get the same equation multiplied by $(-1)$].

Comment: Many thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy, what you suggested holds: $I_{ \{ b \leqslant x\}} -I_{ \{ a \leqslant x\}} = I_{ \{ \min\{a,b\}\leqslant x \leqslant \max\{a,b\} \}}$. I used $\min, \max$ as I don't know which element is greater.

Comment: @Alex Please see the remark I have added to my answer.

Comment: Many thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy, that's very helpful! I will adjust my steps accordingly in the question.